# Daddy, let me do swelling on you

Tags: grammar

He fell down and got a swollen bump.

I put a ice pack on it.

How do we say if we use other thing such as cold fruit to do swelling?

My son took a cold orange and pretend to do a swelling on my knee.

> "Daddy, let me do **swelling** on you."

Does it sound natural to a native speaker?

Comment: When something swells it gets big. The part of the body which is getting big does the swelling. It sounds like you are talking about **treating** a swelling by putting a cold compress on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "do swelling", but rather "(some injury) caused swelling" or "(some body part) got swollen".

> He fell down, which **caused** his knee **to become swollen**.
>   His knee **got swollen**. (indirect and informal)

As for the swelling itself, the cold will "*reduce* the swelling" or "make the swelling *go down*".